# Different possible row combinations in R

Tags: r

Currently I am working on a personal project and I am trying to figure out how to differently combine rows based on the `PURCHASE_DATE`.

Where Day 20 and 25 is repeated twice, so the number of possible results (#data frames) would be 2 * 1 * 2 = 4.

This is my data frame:

```
  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
1  A       66           20
2  B       83           20
3  B       62           23
4  C       72           25
5  B       96           25
```

I want my result to be:

```
  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
1  A       66           20
3  B       62           23
4  C       72           25

  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
1  A       66           20
3  B       62           23
5  B       96           25

  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
2  B       83           20
3  B       62           23
4  C       72           25

  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
2  B       83           20
3  B       62           23
5  B       96           25
```

Comment: This seems like a potentially unrepresentative example. Is it always like this, where just one purchase date is repeated? What if multiple purchase dates are repeated? What if some are repeated different numbers of times?

Comment: There should be more than 4 outputted data.frames, yes? You've shown different prices for `ABC`, but there are countless other combinations, yes? In fact there should be `5 * 4 * 3` data.frames outputted.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Gregor. I just modified the current case. Please review it and give me some feedback. 

What I need is the code that would allow me to print this output.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess combinations are determined by unique purchase dates. there are 2 purchase date `20`, 1 purchase date `23`, and 2 purchase date `25`, so 2 * 1 * 2 = 4 possible outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your response InfiniteFlashChess. We get different combinations based on the unique # of dates. In this case we have 3 different dates: 20, 23 and 25, where 20 and 25 are repeated twice each.  So the number of possible data frames should be: 2 * 1 * 2 = 4. Just like @Gregor mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice way returning a `list`. Calling your data `dd`:

```
ddsplit = split(1:nrow(dd), dd$PURCHASE_DATE)
rows = expand.grid(ddsplit)

result = apply(rows, 1, function(x) dd[x, ])
result
# [[1]]
#   ITEM PRICE PURCHASE_DATE
# 1    A    66            20
# 3    B    62            23
# 4    C    72            25
# 
# [[2]]
#   ITEM PRICE PURCHASE_DATE
# 2    B    83            20
# 3    B    62            23
# 4    C    72            25
# 
# [[3]]
#   ITEM PRICE PURCHASE_DATE
# 1    A    66            20
# 3    B    62            23
# 5    B    96            25
# 
# [[4]]
#   ITEM PRICE PURCHASE_DATE
# 2    B    83            20
# 3    B    62            23
# 5    B    96            25
```

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "  ITEM    PRICE      PURCHASE_DATE
1  A       66           20
2  B       83           20
3  B       62           23
4  C       72           25
5  B       96           25", header = T)
```